# What will $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return if i have multiple pages opened in my browser

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
  $x = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
?>
```

I'm running this on `localhost` in an HTML page. What will `x` be if I have multiple pages opened on the same `localhost`?

This code gets executed into a JavaScript `onclick` function.

Comment: Yeah no I realized the mistake. So if I run this piece of code into an HTML code will I get the HTML address no matter of other tabs in the browser ?

Comment: ok ty that answers my question

Comment: not sure what you intend to achieve, but i looks like you want to use sessions, https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.session.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x will be nothing because the syntax is wrong. You could write it as

```
$x = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

But this makes no sense to combine those values.

- `HTTP_HOST` is the domain name (of the current http server)
- `REQUEST_URI` the URL from the browsers address bar.

Every tab (request) stands for its own, so the variable will have it's own content on each tab. It could be the same, if the request is also the same.

You will get no summary.

The [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server) will provide you all infos available.